# How to move some columns of a table to a new table and save the ids back to original table

Tags: mysql, sql

In the MySQL database, I have a table "places" with the 4 columns:

```
id | street | city | name
```

and I would like to change the table so that it becomes:

table addresses:

```
id | street | city
```

places table:

```
id | address_id | name
```

and apparently, address_id is fk to the id of the address table.

What is the best approach that preferably can be put in a script, so that I can repeatedly do it for localhost, dev and prod env?

Comment: MYSQL or SQL-server?

Comment: Which table is the parent here? addresses or places? I guess you will create one autonumeric column on the new child table?

Comment: Do you already have data in your current "Places" table? If you do, you'll need to migrate it, since you'll be dropping two columns and moving them to another table.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you need is a [VIEW](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/create-sql-views-mysql.aspx) and a new `places` table. If you're not familiar with the concept, a view is a virtual table that is generated off the real table(s) and updated constantly, so you don't have to recreate any tables.  So:

```
CREATE VIEW addresses AS
    SELECT id as address_id, street, city
    FROM places;
```

I'm going to assume that you're not just looking to have the original ID in the new `places` twice, so create your new table with an `AUTO_INCREMENT` id field and the other columns you want, and then you can run an insert whenever you need to:

```
INSERT INTO places_new
    (address_id, name)
SELECT 
    a.address_id, p.name
FROM places AS p
INNER JOIN addresses as a
on p.id = a.address_id
```

Comment: The view will probably have duplicate rows for the same `street, city`. I guess OP needs only unique ones.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- create table addresses with the required columns size and indexes
-- if you have any existing data, insert it in the new table
INSERT INTO Addresses
SELECT Street, City FROM Places

-- if you have any constraints on those columns, remove them
ALTER TABLE Places DROP Street, City
ALTER TABLE PLACES ADD Address_Id int
-- add foreign key constraint
```

Comment: A reference from  Places to Addresses is missing